# R function to mutate multiple columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am working a drug registry data. I want to calculate doses of oral drugs prescribed before diagnosis. In the example data, dia_date stands for date of diagnosis and ddd stands for doses.

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~id,  ~drug_group,    ~drug_type, ~prescribed_date,   ~dia_date,  ~ddd,
  1,    "A",    "oral",     2010,   2020,   1,  
  1,    "B",    "non-oral", 2011,   2020,   2,  
  2,    "A",    "oral",     2019,   2020,   1,  
  2,    "B",    "oral",     2019,   2020,   1,  
  2,    "C",    "oral",     2008,   2021,   2,  
  3,    "A",    "oral",     2021,   2020,   2,  
  3,    "C",    "non-oral", 2009,   2021,   2,  
  4,    "A",    "oral",     2010,   2020,   NA )
```

The output should be like

```
df2 <- tribble(
~id,    ~drug_group,    ~drug_type, ~prescribed_date,   ~dia_date,  ~ddd,   ~ddd_a, ~ddd_b, ~ddd_c,
1,  "A",    "oral",     2010,   2020,   1,  1,  0,  0,
1,  "B",    "non-oral", 2011,   2020,   2,  0,  0,  0,
2,  "A",    "oral",     2019,   2020,   1,  1,  0,  0,
2,  "B",    "oral",     2019,   2020,   1,  0,  1,  0,
2,  "C",    "oral",     2008,   2021,   2,  0,  0,  2,
3,  "A",    "oral",     2021,   2020,   2,  0,  0,  0,
3,  "C",    "non-oral", 2009,   2021,   2,  0,  0,  0,
4,  "A",    "oral",     2010,   2020,   NA, 0,  0,  0 )
```

In the actual dataset, the drug groups are  more than >20.
I tried with the following  codes, but to no avail.

```
##Attempt1
 for (col in c("a","b","c")){
  ddd_= paste0("ddd_",col)
  df1[,ddd_] = df1$ddd
}

for (i in c("ddd_a","ddd_b","ddd_c")){
  if (df1$prescribed_date>df1$dia_date & df1$drug_group!="oral"){
    df1[,i] <- 0
  }
}

##Attempt2
for (col in c("a","b","c")){
  ddd_= paste0("ddd_",col)
  df1[,ddd_] = df1$ddd
}
f <- function (x) ifelse(df1$prescribed_date>df1$dia_date & df1$drug_group!="oral",0,x)
df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("ddd_")), f)
```

I would really appreciate if any help.

Comment: Why does `id` 3 at `drug_group` "A" not have 2 doses for `ddd_a`?

Comment: Drug group "A" for id 3 was prescribed (2021) after diagnosis (2020). That's why it was excluded as I want pre-diagnostic drug exposure.

Comment: Edited my post to match that requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reshape2`'s `dcast`:

```
df1 %>%
  dcast(id+drug_group+drug_type+prescribed_date+dia_date+ddd ~ drug_group, length) %>%
  mutate_at(.funs = list(ddd = ~.*ddd*(drug_type == "oral")*(prescribed_date <= dia_date)), .vars = vars(A:C)) %>%
  select(-c(A:C))
```

which produces:

```
  id drug_group drug_type prescribed_date dia_date ddd A_ddd B_ddd C_ddd
1  1          A      oral            2010     2020   1     1     0     0
2  1          B  non-oral            2011     2020   2     0     0     0
3  2          A      oral            2019     2020   1     1     0     0
4  2          B      oral            2019     2020   1     0     1     0
5  2          C      oral            2008     2021   2     0     0     2
6  3          A      oral            2021     2020   2     0     0     0
7  3          C  non-oral            2009     2021   2     0     0     0
8  4          A      oral            2010     2020  NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I tried the suggested codes. But I got ````Error in eval(variables_names, envir = envir, enclos = baseenv()) :  object 'A' not found ```` . Could you please help? I also would like to know  the meaning of ``` ~.*ddd* ``` in ```mutate_at``` functions.

Comment: so about the `mutate_at`, without the `*ddd` all you will get are 0s and 1s, is the `drug_type `A (1) or not A (0), by multiplying with ddd you get the doses and in case of NA you will get NA. I am not sure about the error you are getting, can you check if i happens in the `mutate_at` or the `select`?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. After checking, the error happened at ```mutate_at``` .

Comment: Hmmm, does the real table have any additional columns? Or are the `drug_groups` different? The `dcast` should create a column for every unique `drug_group`, which includes "A" in the table you provided. Try running only the dcast to see which columns are created

Comment: When I tried ``` .vars=c(7:9)``` instead of ``` .vars=var(A:C)```, I got the desired output. Direct variable name ``` .vars=var(A:C)``` seems not working. How can I use the direct variable name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236931/discussion-between-moonlu-and-wietse-de-vries).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  #Keep data for only 'oral' drug type
  filter(drug_type == 'oral') %>%
  #Create temporary columns
  mutate(temp = ddd, 
         name = paste0('ddd_', drug_group)) %>%
  #Keep selected columns
  select(id, drug_group, ddd:name) %>%
  #Get the data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = temp, values_fill = 0) %>%
  #Join with the original dataset
  right_join(df1, by = c('id', 'drug_group', 'ddd')) %>%
  #Replace NA with 0
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

#     id drug_group   ddd ddd_A ddd_B ddd_C drug_type prescribed_date dia_date
#  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1 A              1     1     0     0 oral                 2010     2020
#2     2 A              1     1     0     0 oral                 2019     2020
#3     2 B              1     0     1     0 oral                 2019     2020
#4     2 C              2     0     0     2 oral                 2008     2021
#5     3 A              2     2     0     0 oral                 2021     2020
#6     4 A              0     0     0     0 oral                 2010     2020
#7     1 B              2     0     0     0 non-oral             2011     2020
#8     3 C              2     0     0     0 non-oral             2009     2021
```